# How to set navbar tabs active when used?

Tags: php, html

this is my second question here, first one was resolved quite quickly and I appreciate any help I get. Here's the thing:

I have a folder views in which I have a folder named _global in which I have my beforeContent.php and afterContent.php those are my header and footer of actual Web pages. The main content in my pages is set in other view folders and I have no problem there.

I have this script in my beforeContent.php (this one shows my navbar):

```
<?php if (Session::exists('user_id')): ?>    
<?php include 'app/views/_global/menu-session.php'; ?>    
<?php else: ?>    
<?php include 'app/views/_global/menu-no-session.php'; ?>    
<?php endif; ?>
```

basically, if a user is logged in, it will show menu-session.php, if there's no user logged in, it will show menu-no-session.php.

my menu-session has this in it:

```html
    <ul>
    <li><a <?php if ($FoundRoute['Controller'] == 'Main') echo 
    'class="active";'?> href="<?php echo Configuration::BASE_URL; ?>">Home</a> 
    </li>
    <li><a <?php if ($FoundRoute['Controller'] == 'Overview') echo 
    'class="active";'?> href="<?php echo Configuration::BASE_URL; ? 
    >overview">Overview</a></li>
    </ul>
```

it has more tabs, but you get the point.

I had to use this function that chooses the controller that will decide if the page is active or not. basically: If i'm on a page Overview, the script asks if the active Controller is named 'Overview' and if it is, it will select the tab as class="active".

However, this is wrong: my teacher said I can't have  scripts in my view files (it's not wrong, it's just bad practice) and I need another method of doing this:

So, I created a method class Misc.php with a function Misc::url:

```
public static function url($link, $text){
        echo '<a href="' . Configuration::BASE_URL . $link . '">' . $text . 
'</a>';
    }
```

this way my menu-session can just be:

```
<ul>
<li>Misc::url('', 'Home')</li>
<li>Misc::url('overview', 'Overview')</li>
</ul>
```

Now: I need a correct function in Misc.php where I have the >>> $FoundRoute['Controller'] <<< if statement implanted, something like:

```
Misc::urlWithActive($link, $text){
if ($foundRoute['Controller] = *thiscontroller*) {
echo '<a href="' . Configuration::BASE_URL . $link . '">' . $text . 
'</a>';
}
```

I actually don't know how to write that.

I Really hope you guys understand what I need to do here and help me.

Comment: I suspect that you'll require third parameter in static `url` method, so that you can compare controller for active class. Also, instead of calling same method multiple times, prepare an array for list items and use `foreach`.